# Facebook Debugger Not Scraping Page With SSL Certificate

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl, https, scrape

I recently installed a SSL certificate on my domain and now Facebook is unable to scrape my webpages for open graph content.

When I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and scrape the site:  https://genesispetaluma.com, I get an error "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped."  When I click to see what the scraper sees, I get a message "document returned no data" at this link:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgenesispetaluma.com%2F.  This worked perfectly before the installation of the SSL Certificate.  Because I do not have a wildcard SSL certificate, I tried to scrape a site on my subdomain:  http://blog.genesispetaluma.com and this passes and delivers the following information:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=blog.genesispetaluma.com.

I have verified with the server logs that Facebook is making a request to my server:  69.171.237.115 - - [22/Aug/2014:09:44:13 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 206 6512 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

I ran a test with  www.ssllabs.com and it appears that the certificate is installed correctly, with all of the intermediate certificates installed as well.  My hosting company has verified that the certificate is installed correctly as well.

Any ideas why this is not working or how I can troubleshoot this?  I posted this issue in the Facebook Developer forum and they have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook team was able to determine the source of the problem.  Facebook will not scrape the page unless the `og:url` has the protocol as well.

For example, this does not work:

```
meta property="og:url" content="//genesispetaluma.com/"
```

But this does:

```
meta property="og:url" content="**https:**//genesispetaluma.com/"
```

They should to clarify the error in the debugger so people know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas why this is not working or how I can troubleshoot this?

There's one small problem that I see that might be causing the problem. The CA certificate is being sent in the chain. The CA certificate is the third certificate shown below.

You should not send the CA in the chain. Rather, the client needs to already have it and use it as a trust anchor.

Another potential issue is that the web app located at https://developers.facebook.com does *not* use the *AddTrust External CA Root* certificate as a trust anchor. If Facebook is missing the trust anchor, or does not trust the CA, then there's nothing you can do.

The final potential issue is an SSL/TLS interception proxy is at work. But I doubt Facebook is intercepting the traffic leaving their network.

---

There's another small problem with the server certificate. The server certificate provides a DNS name in the Common Name (CN). Placing a DNS in the Common Name is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/Browser forums. Though its deprecated, its not forbidden.

DNS names should be placed in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN), and both genesispetaluma.com and www.genesispetaluma.com are there. So that looks OK.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect genesispetaluma.com:443 -CAfile addtrustexternalcaroot.crt | openssl x509 -text -noout
depth=2 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = PositiveSSL CA 2
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = Hosted by A Small Orange LLC, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = genesispetaluma.com
verify return:1
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            86:c2:2e:29:7b:68:f7:f3:16:5d:18:27:84:1f:e4:98
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar  3 00:00:00 2014 GMT
            Not After : Mar  3 23:59:59 2015 GMT
        Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, OU=Hosted by A Small Orange LLC, OU=PositiveSSL, CN=genesispetaluma.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e1:16:f6:78:f8:10:29:e8:96:e6:3b:f1:2f:36:
                    3f:da:2f:cf:b8:f3:ab:cb:3b:8c:a6:09:0a:a6:3a:
                    f3:e9:ad:7f:d7:30:c4:ac:b3:9b:98:e0:ec:f0:2a:
                    75:31:e4:0b:92:76:cc:a3:49:b6:bc:35:77:29:ed:
                    aa:51:20:b5:c1:b0:1f:ed:ee:23:84:29:99:d4:a2:
                    6c:c5:5e:66:dc:7e:cf:b7:9d:88:c8:75:1a:46:ec:
                    ce:34:db:da:06:4e:b0:8d:21:ec:2c:db:88:8e:1f:
                    9b:13:76:ca:30:8c:4b:60:d5:02:f4:91:a9:d6:b3:
                    3b:c8:46:2d:0d:90:04:c5:39:ca:e7:e2:20:fe:57:
                    95:bc:40:9b:af:52:9b:fd:95:54:a6:82:f9:d7:ea:
                    ac:e5:08:1a:53:c2:7b:59:2b:23:a2:12:41:58:4c:
                    6c:f0:fe:56:77:ed:ae:0f:9a:5d:b5:32:1c:51:3b:
                    46:56:d2:60:a4:ad:91:56:11:a6:f4:fc:1b:94:22:
                    84:9f:a2:c0:80:92:01:48:58:9a:d1:01:11:5f:99:
                    95:05:c8:18:23:dc:72:e4:d8:01:24:f0:c6:26:23:
                    be:b3:09:ea:22:94:f6:04:c4:9a:67:3c:15:b1:25:
                    24:49:7d:60:31:5c:60:a5:f9:7b:65:9d:45:91:fd:
                    a4:f3
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:99:E4:40:5F:6B:14:5E:3E:05:D9:DD:D3:63:54:FC:62:B8:F7:00:AC

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                3E:E8:E1:02:B6:36:96:64:7F:9A:84:2E:DD:17:F9:D9:C5:88:A7:EF
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.7
                  CPS: http://www.positivessl.com/CPS
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.comodoca.com/PositiveSSLCA2.crl

            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://crt.comodoca.com/PositiveSSLCA2.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.comodoca.com

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:genesispetaluma.com, DNS:www.genesispetaluma.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         53:20:9f:af:fd:c4:20:78:ed:56:ed:53:8d:29:38:3b:16:00:
         ff:7f:39:fd:75:21:b1:d7:af:27:e5:08:d2:c5:77:5e:52:09:
         fd:38:ba:03:a3:8c:4d:e9:8f:6e:a7:12:c4:26:b2:1f:02:96:
         f8:24:94:0c:c4:74:2a:2d:2e:b4:d6:4c:ee:5f:2d:e1:b6:91:
         a3:eb:d0:9a:46:fa:f5:c1:da:a0:13:11:63:56:64:08:e3:f2:
         2c:7a:80:19:1f:a1:4e:ae:9e:ab:1e:27:71:ed:55:da:dc:2b:
         b0:52:73:ed:e7:1b:c2:2f:5d:6a:17:90:ee:32:b2:36:ee:9c:
         8e:57:5b:70:bd:08:55:1c:a2:f4:ca:ee:f4:0b:0e:d7:1a:e3:
         e8:de:14:eb:d0:62:24:9a:8b:7c:c6:ab:65:35:e1:5d:a0:2f:
         1f:7a:d2:96:e7:0c:12:cc:d8:e7:ff:1c:58:0c:ce:db:6d:cc:
         e8:f7:09:17:57:a8:cc:b7:90:4e:f3:0a:2e:d3:56:ad:44:12:
         ce:b1:4c:9b:2a:5c:3f:1e:19:95:41:7a:f9:2c:15:c5:48:c6:
         bd:49:ad:f6:95:15:21:69:58:a2:0e:c2:9f:9f:c4:a9:d7:83:
         a4:6f:5b:07:c5:28:65:8e:fe:fa:83:5f:5f:10:12:36:c8:c9:
         f0:55:7a:a0
```

---

> I tried to scrape a site on my subdomain: http://blog.genesispetaluma.com and this passes

This is odd. The certificate above does *not* certify blog.genesispetaluma.com. This should fail validation.

---

If you want to use OpenSSL's `s_client` to verify the chain, then go to [[Root] AddTrust External CA Root](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/917/91/) and download the *AddTrust External CA Root* certificate. Then use the `CAfile` option and you should receive `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect genesispetaluma.com:443 -showcerts \
                   -CAfile addtrustexternalcaroot.crt
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: A171C87253621808B164BAA1399B07D776E28EBCB8A5AB3A81D65DD66505E3AF
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 559289812A3602C49FEC4C6FEDC714D4D7B107BDB4E9AD5A811DD0606EF5114D
                4DD2624EE141508E92092CF23D946185
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - f4 67 cf 21 46 b8 f9 ae-ba ec da f4 2a 24 9f 5b   .g.!F.......*$.[
    ...
    00b0 - b8 97 35 30 cf c6 83 a6-14 a6 b7 16 b1 6c 50 b6   ..50.........lP.

    Start Time: 1408754636
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

---

Here's the certificate chain with the CA certificate:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect genesispetaluma.com:443 -showcerts -CAfile addtrustexternalcaroot.crt 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = PositiveSSL CA 2
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = Hosted by A Small Orange LLC, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = genesispetaluma.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by A Small Orange LLC/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=genesispetaluma.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE5TCCA82gAwIBAgIQB28SRoFFnCjVSNaXxA4AGzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBv
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJTRTEUMBIGA1UEChMLQWRkVHJ1c3QgQUIxJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFk
ZFRydXN0IEV4dGVybmFsIFRUUCBOZXR3b3JrMSIwIAYDVQQDExlBZGRUcnVzdCBF
eHRlcm5hbCBDQSBSb290MB4XDTEyMDIxNjAwMDAwMFoXDTIwMDUzMDEwNDgzOFow
czELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
A1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxGTAXBgNV
BAMTEFBvc2l0aXZlU1NMIENBIDIwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEK
AoIBAQDo6jnjIqaqucQA0OeqZztDB71Pkuu8vgGjQK3g70QotdA6voBUF4V6a4Rs
NjbloyTi/igBkLzX3Q+5K05IdwVpr95XMLHo+xoD9jxbUx6hAUlocnPWMytDqTcy
Ug+uJ1YxMGCtyb1zLDnukNh1sCUhYHsqfwL9goUfdE+SNHNcHQCgsMDqmOK+ARRY
FygiinddUCXNmmym5QzlqyjDsiCJ8AckHpXCLsDl6ez2PRIHSD3SwyNWQezT3zVL
yOf2hgVSEEOajBd8i6q8eODwRTusgFX+KJPhChFo9FJXb/5IC1tdGmpnc5mCtJ5D
YD7HWyoSbhruyzmuwzWdqLxdsC/DAgMBAAGjggF3MIIBczAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSt
vZh6NLQm9/rEJlTvA73gJMtUGjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUmeRAX2sUXj4F2d3TY1T8Yrj3
AKwwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwEQYDVR0gBAow
CDAGBgRVHSAAMEQGA1UdHwQ9MDswOaA3oDWGM2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwudXNlcnRydXN0
LmNvbS9BZGRUcnVzdEV4dGVybmFsQ0FSb290LmNybDCBswYIKwYBBQUHAQEEgaYw
gaMwPwYIKwYBBQUHMAKGM2h0dHA6Ly9jcnQudXNlcnRydXN0LmNvbS9BZGRUcnVz
dEV4dGVybmFsQ0FSb290LnA3YzA5BggrBgEFBQcwAoYtaHR0cDovL2NydC51c2Vy
dHJ1c3QuY29tL0FkZFRydXN0VVROU0dDQ0EuY3J0MCUGCCsGAQUFBzABhhlodHRw
Oi8vb2NzcC51c2VydHJ1c3QuY29tMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCcNuNOrvGK
u2yXjI9LZ9Cf2ISqnyFfNaFbxCtjDei8d12nxDf9Sy2e6B1pocCEzNFti/OBy59L
dLBJKjHoN0DrH9mXoxoR1Sanbg+61b4s/bSRZNy+OxlQDXqV8wQTqbtHD4tc0azC
e3chUN1bq+70ptjUSlNrTa24yOfmUlhNQ0zCoiNPDsAgOa/fT0JbHtMJ9BgJWSrZ
6EoYvzL7+i1ki4fKWyvouAt+vhcSxwOCKa9Yr4WEXT0K3yNRw82vEL+AaXeRCk/l
uuGtm87fM04wO+mPZn+C+mv626PAcwDj1hKvTfIPWhRRH224hoFiB85ccsJP81cq
cdnUl4XmGFO3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by A Small Orange LLC/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=genesispetaluma.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4373 bytes and written 434 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: A171C87253621808B164BAA1399B07D776E28EBCB8A5AB3A81D65DD66505E3AF
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 559289812A3602C49FEC4C6FEDC714D4D7B107BDB4E9AD5A811DD0606EF5114D4DD2624EE141508E92092CF23D946185
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - f4 67 cf 21 46 b8 f9 ae-ba ec da f4 2a 24 9f 5b   .g.!F.......*$.[
    0010 - d3 01 c1 21 60 54 8b 1a-8f 5f 5f d5 16 e5 97 11   ...!`T...__.....
    0020 - 0f 63 22 5a d3 59 f3 96-a1 3a 35 93 b9 7c 40 9d   .c"Z.Y...:5..|@.
    0030 - 1d 15 3c 03 04 30 7b 0c-fa fd 69 fc cf ac 32 8c   ..<..0{...i...2.
    0040 - e2 f2 91 48 37 9b 11 ca-f6 b4 e8 65 5f f2 90 31   ...H7......e_..1
    0050 - 8c 2c 7a 74 2e 9a ab de-1f 31 05 b6 a7 6e 42 8b   .,zt.....1...nB.
    0060 - 6d 36 10 38 38 9f f5 1f-c8 e3 ac ce ba 95 21 4f   m6.88.........!O
    0070 - 21 3f 38 ef 20 33 f4 b8-86 6a 61 4b e9 cc 00 4d   !?8. 3...jaK...M
    0080 - ab f3 c6 24 33 3c c5 44-1c 4a f9 71 9b 3c 25 74   ...$3<.D.J.q.<%t
    0090 - af 63 73 d7 b3 1b 4f cc-fe 05 76 75 02 db 5b 12   .cs...O...vu..[.
    00a0 - 8d 2c 5e 7a 98 ca 95 1c-1a 04 df 6e 22 c3 f2 55   .,^z.......n"..U
    00b0 - b8 97 35 30 cf c6 83 a6-14 a6 b7 16 b1 6c 50 b6   ..50.........lP.

    Start Time: 1408754636
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: _“This is odd. The certificate above does not certify blog.genesispetaluma.com. This should fail validation.”_ – he’s not using HTTPS there, but HTTP only. (Probably just an attempt to verify that it is not a problem with the site’s content in general.)